# How do I change a hamburger menu svg from animating when it is being hovered on to animating when it is clicked

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a svg hamburger that animates into a X when hovered on but I would like it to animate to a X when clicked on and then when clicked again it will animate back into its original hamburger form. If this is easier or only able to be done with adding js that is fine.

```css
.hj {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburg {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.hj,
.top,
.middle,
.bottom {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.hj:hover {
  .top {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: center top;
    x: 37.5px;
    y: 26.25px;
  }
  .middle {
    opacity: 0;
    x: 0;
  }
  .bottom {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: center top;
    x: -15px;
    y: 18.75px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="svg.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hamburg">
    <svg class="hj" height="75" width="75" viewBox="0 0 75 75">
            <rect class="top" x="15" y="21.75" width="45" height="5"></rect>
            <rect class="middle" x="15" y="34.1809" width="45" height="5"></rect> 
            <rect class="bottom" x="15" y="46.6117" width="45" height="5"></rect> 
        </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you describe what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a litle of javsacript code to toggle a class to element, and apply same hover styles to active class

```js
const hamburg = document.querySelector(".hamburg");
const activeClass = "active";

hamburg.addEventListener("click", () => {
   hamburg.classList.toggle(activeClass);
});
```

```css
.hj {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburg {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.hj,
.top,
.middle,
.bottom {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburg.active .hj .top,
.hj:hover .top {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: center top;
    x: 37.5px;
    y: 26.25px;
}

.hamburg.active .hj .middle,
.hj:hover .middle {
    opacity: 0;
    x: 0;
}

.hamburg.active .hj .bottom,
.hj:hover .bottom {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: center top;
    x: -15px;
    y: 18.75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburg">
    <svg class="hj" height="75" width="75" viewBox="0 0 75 75">
            <rect class="top" x="15" y="21.75" width="45" height="5"></rect>
            <rect class="middle" x="15" y="34.1809" width="45" height="5"></rect> 
            <rect class="bottom" x="15" y="46.6117" width="45" height="5"></rect> 
        </svg>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will in fact need to use JavaScript to achieve this feature. To handle the change of the hamburger into an X and back, you can toggle a CSS class on the SVG element using JavaScript and listen for a click event on it.

First, give the SVG element an ID attribute.
Then include a new CSS class named "open" that manages the hamburger's transition after being clicked.
Toggling the "open" class on click requires the addition of the following JavaScript code.

Here is the following code:

```js
const svg = document.getElementById("hj");
svg.addEventListener("click", function() {
    svg.classList.toggle("open");
});
```

```css
.hj {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburg {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.hj,
.top,
.middle,
.bottom {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.hj:hover .top,
.hj.open .top {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
  x: 37.5px;
  y: 26.25px;
}

.hj:hover .middle,
.hj.open .middle {
  opacity: 0;
  x: 0;
}

.hj:hover .bottom,
.hj.open .bottom {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: center top;
  x: -15px;
  y: 18.75px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hamburg">
      <svg id="hj" class="hj" height="75" width="75" viewBox="0 0 75 75">
        <rect class="top" x="15" y="21.75" width="45" height="5"></rect>
        <rect class="middle" x="15" y="34.1809" width="45" height="5"></rect>
        <rect class="bottom" x="15" y="46.6117" width="45" height="5"></rect>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Need a Little bit of Javascript and little modification in CSS which can solve this check the below code snippet for this

```js
const hamburg = document.querySelector(".hj");
hamburg.addEventListener("click", () => {
   hamburg.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
.hj {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburg {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.hj,
.top,
.middle,
.bottom {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.hj.open {
  .top {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: center top;
    x: 37.5px;
    y: 26.25px;
  }
  .middle {
    opacity: 0;
    x: 0;
  }
  .bottom {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: center top;
    x: -15px;
    y: 18.75px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="svg.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hamburg">
    <svg class="hj" height="75" width="75" viewBox="0 0 75 75">
            <rect class="top" x="15" y="21.75" width="45" height="5"></rect>
            <rect class="middle" x="15" y="34.1809" width="45" height="5"></rect> 
            <rect class="bottom" x="15" y="46.6117" width="45" height="5"></rect> 
        </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this will solve your issue